# Visual Studio 2012 Line-Number/Outlining Gutter Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The gutter that runs down the left hand side of the code display has disappeared from my install of visual studio 2012. Bellow is a picture of my current install which is missing the gutter and inset in the green border is a correctly working install from a VM. I've uninstalled and reinstalled today; I've deleted the contents of both `AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0` & `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`; I've deleted the entire reg trees of `HKCU/software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/11.0` & `HKLM/software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/11.0` and also tried running `devenv` with the `/rootsuffix` switch set to test1, test2 etc to get it to run from a different registry/appdata location. I've checked the *"Enter outlining mode when files open"* option in *Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced*.

The gutter is also missing if I create a C++ application.

I've completely run dry, any ideas how i might get it back?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and it appears that VsVim extension removes line numbers and adds them only if you write "set number" in your .vimrc file.

Comment: also applied to Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this same issue, and **clearing my temporary files** resolved it.

I noticed the issue was accompanied by an error that would pop up immediately after Visual Studio started:

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
>
> You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

At the bottom of that log file was an error:

```
<entry>
  <record>711</record>
  <time>2015/02/26 19:53:19.159</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>ProfilesRoamingClient</source>
  <description>Path.GetTempFileName threw IOException: The file exists.&#x000D;&#x000A;.</description>
</entry>
```

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx), `Path.GetTempFileName()` throws `IOException` when all of the possible names have been exhausted:

> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if it is used to create more than 65535 files without deleting previous temporary files.
>
> The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if no unique temporary file name is available. To resolve this error, delete all unneeded temporary files.

[`Path.GetTempFileName()` uses](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cbf46fb0b6a0b209ed1caf4a680910b383e68cba/src/mscorlib/src/System/IO/Path.cs#L1011) the [native Windows API function `GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991.aspx) to create temporary files. I took a peek in my temp folder, and it was indeed full to the brim with `tmpXXXX.tmp` files.

I can only assume that some part of setting up those gutters involves creating a temp file, and since that was unsuccessful, it couldn't continue.

Comment: Thanks... You saved my day. Delete this: C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: WOW thank you for posting this! I spent basically all of my work day trying to figure out how to stop that exception error from popping up and getting my code folding and line numbers back. This was the answer. What a random issue.

Answer (score 4):

for **line number** go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General -> Display.

check line number checkbox to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but for markup files.

Try to stop outlining using `Edit -> Outlining -> Stop Outlining` and restarting it with `Edit -> Outlining -> Start Automatic Outlining`.

Also take a look at [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/8e42b539-d2a5-48f8-a718-a97f64b3a7f0/) and let me know if it helped you!

Comment: I've tried going through Lucy-Liu's 4 point list:
**1:** Safe mode as same user: Gutter is still missing.
**2:** Different user(not safe mode): Gutter is back.
**3:** Using /resetsettings with original user: Gutter is still missing.
**4:** I tried a repair yesterday: The gutter is still missing.

Answer (score 2):

Switch line number for all languages **off** and **back on** again.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General > Display.

You probably thought (like I did) that it was already on for all languages. But the options mean:

[image]

Linenumbers for all languages are switched on or off, but **one or more languages differ**.

---

[image]

Linenumbers for all languages are switched on

---

[image]

Linenumbers for all languages are switched off

Answer (score 0):

Try devenv /resetuserdata to wipe off all user specific data. Once done start VS2012 and enable the line number options in your language settings within Tools->Options.

Comment: That didn't bring it back either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the only way round this seems to be running as a different user; the work around I've set up is to change all my shortcuts to devenv.exe to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:VisualStudio /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

And I've stopped .sln files from being opened directly with visual studio and send them through a batch file, which uses a python script to format and execute a runas command.

So .sln files are opened with vs.bat:

```
C:\Python33\py\vs.py %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

With runs vs.py:

```
#python 3.3.0

import sys
import subprocess

count=0;

command = "runas /user:VisualStudio /savecred \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

for arg in sys.argv:
    # Ignore first arg - its this file
    if(count > 0):
             command = command + " \\\""+arg+"\\\""
    count = count + 1

command = command + "\""
print("")
print(command)

subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Which creates a correctly formatted run as command and launches visual studio for the user 'VisualStudio'.

The biggest draw back of this so far is that .sln files pinned to the visual studio icon in the task bar/start menu still get launched under my account; and I can't find a way round that.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation:

I noticed this happening for SOME files, but not others. Line numbers were turned on in the options, and Source Outlining was also turned on. Yet it was not visible for SOME of my files.

Taking the "clearing temporary files" as my inspiration, I just shut down and restarted Visual Studio (in my case, 2013).

Worked!